# Insulating inside walls of old house

Tags: walls, insulation

We have a 120+ year old farmhouse in South Central Illinois. We removed all interior plaster and lath and want to insulate the walls. What is best way to insulate?

I have been researching for a week now and have seen MANY different answers.
The house has new double pane vinyl windows, sheathing on the exterior of the stud wall, original wood siding on the sheathing and vinyl siding over the wood siding. No insulation or vapor barrier on the outside of the house.

Also has two bedrooms upstairs that does not cover the entire upstairs area...when we removed the plaster and lath on the ceiling, the area around the upper bedrooms are open on all 4 sides.

Comment: "Best way" is highly variable or subject to being opinion.Budget tradeoffs often come into play as well. Being in a **primary heating climate**, vapor barrier to the inside.

Comment: There are two common approaches: R13 fiberglass and poly sheeting, or spray foam. Pick the one that fits your skills, budget, and timeline and go forth. Good luck with your project.

Comment: VTC as opinion-based.

Comment: Walls are open, dense pack cellulose is a good option. but as we see and say, opinion...

Comment: With the walls opened, one option is to build inward to make a thicker wall for more insulation space - that can be rigid foam over cavity insulation, or an independent wall structure to make a deeper cavity.

Comment: Does "best" include a cost factor or do you have $$$$$ to throw at the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although it can' t answer the question for the best solution,
a fast, accurate  and very easy method for insulation simulation is offered on the site [www.ubakus.com](http://www.ubakus.com).
The very important parameters dew points,  moisture and drying time can be seen in seconds, thus disclosing any critical layer combination that could effect the health and damage the walls.

Maybe there is a subsidies program in Illinois - here in Europe some threshold values must be met in order to get public subsidies. And sometimes there is a jungle of different programs, offered by city, county, country - besides tax reduction. Here is a screenshot from another insulation question.[image: screenshot]